# Prove that for any $k$, $\lambda$, and $\delta$ there exists a simple graph with $k \leq \lambda \leq \delta$.

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness

> Assume that $G$ is a connected graph.
>
> - Let $k$ be the minimum number of vertices we can remove from $G$ so that it becomes disconnected,
> - Let $\lambda$ be the minimum number of edges we can remove from $G$ so that it becomes disconnected.
> - Let $\delta$ be the minimum degree of the vertices of $G$.
>
> Prove that for every three integers like $k$, $\lambda$, and $\delta$ such that $ 0 \lt k \le \lambda \le \delta$, a simple graph $G$ exists.

I found examples of making graphs like these (not a proof) and in the examples, they use two copies a graph with $\delta$ vertices. In a website I saw it was a complete graph. In another one I found a bipartite graph was used to make our desired graph. So probably these things are related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the disjoint union of two complete graphs on $\delta+2$ vertices. Select $k$ vertices from one of the components and $\lambda$ vertices from the other, and for each of the $\lambda$ vertices add an edge from it to one of the $k$ vertices of the other, being sure to hit each of the $k$ vertices at least once.

Note that each vertex has minimum degree at least $\delta$, that removing the $k$ vertices will disconnect the graph (and no other set of $k$ or fewer vertices will), and that removing all the edges between the $\lambda$ vertices and $k$ vertices will disconnect the graph.